# Add an alternative LDAP server in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, ldap, jboss7.x

I've set up a login-module in my JBoss 7.1 server using LDAP like that:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">
    <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ldap.domain.com:port"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
    <module-option name="principalDNPrefix" value="uid="/>
    <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value=",ou=peoples,dc=domain,dc=com"/>
    <module-option name="searchTimeLimit" value="5000"/>
    <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL"/>
</login-module>
```

But, sometimes, this LDAP server maintained by my company crashes and I like to specify an alternative LDAP server (who exists) in my configuration.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to use a space separated list:

ie:

```
<module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ldap.domain.com:port ldap://ldap2.domain.com:port"/>
```

See: [JNDI LDAP & LDAPS URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/url.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an LDAP Directory Proxy Server to manage the high-availability of the LDAP service. This method removes the dependency of the application server requiring knowledge of more than one specific IP address or hostname - resulting in a simpler configuration that is easier to use, maintain, and operate.